# Drawing to an existing view

Tags: android

How do I add, say, a line to an already drawn view?

I tried grabbing the canvas from the draw method and using it to draw to, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

   super.onDraw(canvas);
   mCanvas = canvas;
       //drawing code here
}

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
             Paint paint = new Paint();
             paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
             paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
             paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
             mCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
      }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Try calling invalidate() on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. if you just want to draw something static, make a member variable as a boolean flag and set it to true when `ACTION_DOWN` was triggered.
2. (for dynamic stuff: save the coordinates for later usage)
3. make a `invalidate()` call in your case block
4. in `onDraw()` draw your line if the flag is true

**edit**

You need to understand the drawing process to understand why saving the canvas object doesn't work.
Android works with two buffers that are flipped (naming them buffer A and B). You draw always on the buffer that isn't visible. After you finished drawing, the buffers will be switched and you will see what you have drawn. Basically the canvas will be locked (to prevent flipping while drawing on the back buffer), and this canvas object will be provided to each view that has requested redrawing. After that the canvas will be unlocked which triggers that the buffers are switched. In that moment this canvas object may still be there, but every drawing you do on it will never be displayed.

A bit more information can be found on my blog [2D Drawing Series](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html)

Comment: OK. So I need to do everything within the onDraw() method.  No way to add a drawing outside of it?

Comment: No, to understand why you should understand the drawing process of android. I will update my answer with a short explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is best done by using a [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). Basically the drawable is an object that capsulates drawing information that can be updated and easily reused. i.e

```
public class LineDrawable extends Drawable {
private int mStartX;

private int mStartY;

private int mEndX;

private int mEndY;

private final Paint mPaint;

public LineDrawable() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}

public void setLineCoordinates(final int startX, final int startY,
        final int endX, final int endY) {
    mStartX = startX;
    mStartY = startY;
    mEndX = endX;
    mEndY = endY;
}

public void setColor(final int color){
    mPaint.setColor(color);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(final ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    mPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(final int alpha) {
    mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawLine(mStartX, mStartY, mEndX, mEndY, mPaint);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
}

public void setSize(final int size){
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(size);
}
}

public class YourView extends View{
private LineDrawable mLineDrawable;

    public YourView(final Context context){
        mLineDrawable = new LineDrawable();
    }

.......

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mLineDrawable.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
           mLineDrawable.setColor(Color.BLUE);
           mLineDrawable.setLineCoordinates(0, 0, event.getX(), event.getY());
       }
     }
}
  }
```

Sorry for the awful formatting, pasting it seems to have messed it up.

Comment: Thank you.  I will use this, too.  But if I, say, wanted to add handles to the line for stretching, I would need to still manipulate this view in the onDraw() method of this view like WarrenFaith mentioned above.

Comment: Also, would need to call this.invalidate() at the end of the onTouchEvent to de-draw the line.

Comment: Yes, a call to invalidate will be needed here as well, my bad for omitting it. If you'd like to add handles - this should be another view with an appropriate onTouchListener set.